# What does "dig ." actually query and where are those IPs coming from?

Tags: dns, dig

Out of curiosity, I entered `dig .` today. To my surprise, I got an IP:

```
$ dig .

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> .
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45964
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.                              IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
.                       291     IN      A       172.217.23.174

;; Query time: 150 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.138#53(10.0.0.138)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 22 18:03:53 STD 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 33
```

Now, this IP seems to belong to Google, and `http://172.217.23.174/` actually redirects to `http://www.google.com/`.

However, trying this repeatedly gave me different IPs: `52.95.34.225` (Amazon), `157.240.1.13` (Facebook), `52.114.128.9` (Microsoft), `23.195.9.143` (Akamai), and others... (this actually reads like the who-is-who of Internet companies!)

Googling each of them never revealed anything special other than the organization they belong to.

So, now I'm even more curious: Where are these IPs coming from? And what does `dig .` actually *do*? It seems to query the "DNS root" which, as I understand, shouldn't have random A records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `.` refers to the DNS "root". Yes, `.` is not supposed to have any record types other than NS and SOA (plus DNSSEC-related RRSIG/DNSKEY if you query with the +dnssec option).

So in this case, you're sending the queries to `10.0.0.138` (which is a private address in your LAN), and it's sending you completley made-up replies. You should investigate who owns that host on your LAN, and why it's configured as your DNS server to begin with.

(Interestingly, it still includes the `ad` (authenticated data) flag, implying that it had DNSSEC-verified the records before responding, which is just more lies and a reminder to not trust the 'ad' flag.)

Comment: `10.0.0.138` is the DSL router and it appears to be a NetGear Genie VEGN2610. It didn't occur to me that the router could be lying to me. Interesting bug, I wonder where it gets those IPs from and if this has any security implications.

Comment: Further tests showed that this gives _a copy of the answer of the last DNS query_. Not interesting security-wise though since I could simply sniff the query packet from the network.